# FlatList numColumns and flex justifyContent issue

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I have a flat list where I would like to display in a grid like fashion using up 100% width of the container however I cannot seem to achieve this with flatlist.
Space-between as I have goes to the sides (as per image) space-around centres the boxes in the container, space evenly does the same, flex-start with a marginRight is not accurate. Not entirely sure how to achieve this? Thanks

```
<FlatList
    numColumns={3}
    columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-between"}}
    contentContainerStyle={{
       marginTop:20 
    }}
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={renderItemComponent}
/>
```

**Issue:** 
Needing like space-between fashion but if theres 2 items in the row, then move second item to middle based on dynamic data?

[image]

Comment: cam you remove **columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-between"}}** and check once.

Comment: Thank you I have tried that but not working the way I would like.

Answer (score 3):

As React Native 0.71 you can do this now

```
<FlatList
numColumns={numColumns}
columnWrapperStyle={{ columnGap: 10 }}
contentContainerStyle={{
   marginTop:20 
}}
data={data}
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
renderItem={<renderItemComponent style={{ flex: 1 / numColumns }} />}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove "columnWrapperStyle"

```
<FlatList
    numColumns={3}
    contentContainerStyle={{
       marginTop:20 
    }}
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={renderItemComponent}
/>
```

Example link: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/5aee23

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I have tried this - as I mentioned I need it to be spaced evenly across the container using 100% width of the container hence why I tried space-between - see my result based on your suggestion - https://imgur.com/YLlT6Lb

Comment: the container in which you have added the flat list seems don't have the full 100% width. If possible share  full code

Comment: Yes is does, container style has flex: 1, width: "100%", the outside wrapper also has flex: 1, width: "100%" (outside white area with marginHorizontal as you can see) each box has a width + height of 80 -(width: 80, height: 80). Do I need to add margin right and left and use Dimensions API ?

Comment: You don't need that but i think some padding or margin is getting applied to your flat list container or to each render item

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `numColumns = 3` and `renderItemComponent` is a component. Then this is the solution to make it works like what you want

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={numColumns}
  contentContainerStyle={{
    marginTop: 20,
  }}
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={<renderItemComponent style={{ flex: 1 / numColumns }} />}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone, in my case {flex:1} style on the list-item container was the reason.

giving the item border a color made me identify that the {flex:1} style on list-item is making the items to take available space equally (2 items in last row sharing available space equally).

[image: Flat List Horizontal]

Removing the {flex:1} style property on child item style made it align properly as in the below image.

[image]